# Dom Walking in perl

Tags: perl, dom

Using the example below. I have an HTML file parsed using [Mojo::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojo::DOM). However I encounter a scenario in one of the pages  has two classes that I need (Question and Answer) to read  comprising of a Label with its corresponding textbox that needs filling. I am having problem retrieving the Label and its corresponding textbox so that I can fill in the right values into the right box.

```
<td class="Question">1</td>
<td class="Answer"><input type="text"/></td>
<td class="Question">2</td>
<td class="Answer"> <input type="text"/></input></td>
<td class="Question">3</td>
</td class="Answer"><input type="text"/></td>
```

Please any ideas on how I can go about it  using perl? Please note that the innertext for each label do change per script run.

Comment: Can you share part of your code doing parsing?

Comment: You've completely changed the question!!! And the HTML you posted seems corrupted?? [Deleted my answer since it no longer applies]

Comment: Why the down vote? is it for asking a question or making a mistake in my question and then correcting it ? It is a learning community is it not.

Comment: Is the </td class="Answer"> on the last line intentional?

Comment: No it is not intentional. A typo on my side when doing the question and trying to mask the real data. It ought not to be there. Editing the mistake has caused issues with Ikegami in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with Mojo::Dom  I was able to select the value of the labels , I then combined it with WWW::Mechanize to fill it into the input text boxes.

```
my $url = "http://MyURL/Path"
my $mech  = WWW::Mechanize->new( agent => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows 
NT 6.1)');
$mech->get($url);
$dom =  Mojo::DOM->new($mech->content);
my @temp =  $dom->find('.Question')->map(sub{$_->text})->each ;
```

The array it return leaves it in order that I wanted.  I got a reference from http://blogs.perl.org/users/joel_berger/2012/05/using-mojodom.html which really helped in case anyone is in need of an easy to use tool.